# Interfaces and Packages

Tags: java, interface

I'm implementing an interface in Java and was wondering why this code:

```
package threaddemo;

// Create a new thread...
class NewThread implements Runnable {
      Thread t;
      NewThread(){
        // Create a second, new thread...
        t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
        System.out.println("Child thread: " + t);
        t.start();
      }

    // This is the entry point for the second thread...
    public void run(){
           try {
               for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
                   System.out.println("Child thread: " + i);
                    // Let the thread sleep for a while...
                    Thread.sleep(500);
               }
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   System.out.println("Child interrupted...");
               }
                   System.out.println("Exiting child thread...");
           } }

public class ThreadDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Create a new thread...
            new NewThread(); 
            try {
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
                    System.out.println("Main thread: " + i);
                       Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Main thread itnerrupted...");
            }
            System.out.println("Main thread exiting...");
    } }
```

generates the following warning to the left of it:

```
Package Field
```

When you implement interfaces, do you gain access to the classes in the package that contain the interface? I have no other files in my package yet and I haven't done any kind of import either, so I'm actually kind of confused as to **why** this is accessible to begin with...

Comment: Can you please post the full warning? Your last paragraph is hard to understand right now.

Comment: It doesn't really say anything besides that. I posted a little more info below if that helps. :-)

Comment: I added the rest of the code if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never seen that warning, so going out on a limb here... Do you have a package defined for the class? Otherwise it could mean that the `Thread t`-member has what most books call *default* visibility or *package-private* visibility (which means package- and class-level visibility), because there's no visibility modifier for the field. Java has 4 different visibilities: public, default, protected, private. See here for more information: [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: I was thinking that, but I'm a little confused because I haven't imported any packages (and my package doesn't contain any other classes) and I didn't create this class. Any idea?

Comment: What editor are you using, I don't recall ever seeing this warning in Eclipse... anyway, could it mean you are missing the `public`-modifier in front of `class NewThread implements Runnable`, so the class is only visible to the same package?

Comment: Adding that actually generated an error.
I guess what I'm trying to say is that I haven't imported any packages, so how come I'm able to create thread objects. The only I've done really is implement an interface.

Comment: @PaulCalabro: see here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_Hints#Encapsulation  "Package Field
    Warns about existence of package visible variables Since NetBeans 6.9 ", so my initial guess was right (it's because the `Thread t`-member has package-private visibility)

Comment: I think we're close, I'm just wondering what package this coming from since I haven't done an import. How is this accessible? haha..

Comment: I have no other class files in this packages either.

Comment: @PaulCalabro What that warning means is that the field `t` is visible to the rest of the package - it doesn't have to do with other packages. Best practice would be to make it `private` and/or `final`.

Comment: @PaulCalabro: Everything in `java.lang.*` -packages and same package inside which the current class resides is available (as long as the visibility modifiers allow it) without a separate `import` declaration.

Comment: @esaj BINGO! That's what I was missing. I didn't realize that. I thought everything external required an import.  Thanks so much guys! You guys rock! Back into the night I go...